# Browser not popping basic authentication login prompt

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, basic-authentication

I am new to basic authentication. I created a dummy web application with no resources in it. Below is the security constraint I added in my web xml file

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>contextRoot</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>AuthorizedUser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>defaultWIMFileBasedRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```

I deployed my application in websphere 8.5 and tried to hit some random resource in this application to check if the browser is challenging me to authenticate. And I don't see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web.xml seemed to be correct and should prompt for basic authentication. But it seems like you do not have any resource (jsp or servlet) in your web project. I created a simple.jsp in a web project and used contents of your web.xml and got prompted with basic authentication challenge. For login to work, you will need to map Security role "AuthorizedUser" to a valid user in your configured user registry or use a special subject as "All Authenticated User".

Sample.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<%= "Hello World!" %>
</body>
</html>
```

If **http://hostname:port/simple.jsp** is called with what you have in web.xml, basic authentication challenge should be prompted.

Comment: Thank you, I enabled application security in websphere and makes users to the role and it worked

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. If the answer resolved your issue, please mark it as accepted.